# How to append text in a richtextbox in VB.NET on a specified line  

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

How can I append text in a rich text box? Say, for example, that I need to append it on line 40 at column 30.

Comment: WinForms in windows desktop application

Comment: this looks answered to me.  Do you need anything else?  If not, please close your thread by marking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take your string, count the lines, then use string manipulation to manually insert your string in the correct position.

You could count lines by counting occurrences of '\n' and for column you just add column number to the position that you find your line at.

If this is too little info, ask me and I can paste you a c# code for it.